# How can I change the color of that purple thing?

Tags: flutter, colors, flutter-layout, textfield, textformfield

How can I change the color of that purple thing?
[image]

Comment: can you drop your code? edit your answer and drop the source code

Comment: Do you mean `outlineBorder`  around textfiled ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This Color depends on your Theme Color, try the below code, I hope it helps you :

```
TextField(cursorColor: Colors.red)//change color your need
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities:

- Change it in all your code. In your main file change it like this :

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.orange, // Or another color
  ),
  home: Home() // Your home page,
);
```

- Change it in this part only

```
TextField( cursorColor: Colors.orange) // or another color
```

Answer (score 0):

In your TextField, specify the cursorColor property, like this:

```
TextField(
...
// put here the color you want
cursorColor: Colors.green
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To change this globally you should do this
In the last updates in flutter the `primaryswatch` would take a `MaterialColor` not a `Color` so I worte a `extension` on `Color` to convert a color to material color

```
extension SuiizColors on Color {
  /// Returns a [MaterialColor] from a [Color] object
  MaterialColor getMaterialColorFromColor() {
    final colorShades = <int, Color>{
      50: ColorsManager.getShade(this, value: 0.5),
      100: ColorsManager.getShade(this, value: 0.4),
      200: ColorsManager.getShade(this, value: 0.3),
      300: ColorsManager.getShade(this, value: 0.2),
      400: ColorsManager.getShade(this, value: 0.1),
      500: this, //Primary value
      600: ColorsManager.getShade(this, value: 0.1, darker: true),
      700: ColorsManager.getShade(this, value: 0.15, darker: true),
      800: ColorsManager.getShade(this, value: 0.2, darker: true),
      900: ColorsManager.getShade(this, value: 0.25, darker: true),
    };
    return MaterialColor(value, colorShades);
  }
}
```

the code for the getShade method is

```
static Color getShade(Color color, {bool darker = false, double value = .1}) {
    assert(value >= 0 && value <= 1, 'shade values must be between 0 and 1');

    final hsl = HSLColor.fromColor(color);
    final hslDark = hsl.withLightness(
      (darker ? (hsl.lightness - value) : (hsl.lightness + value))
          .clamp(0.0, 1.0),
    );

    return hslDark.toColor();
  }
```

finally you can add you need to add your primary swatch and your color scheme to delete this

```
 primarySwatch: ColorsManager.primary.getMaterialColorFromColor(),
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
        primarySwatch: Colors.transparent.getMaterialColorFromColor(),
        accentColor: ColorsManager.accent,
        backgroundColor: ColorsManager.white,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        cardColor: ColorsManager.offWhite,
        errorColor: ColorsManager.error),
```

sorry for the long answer but it's better in my opinion